# Find nearest distance of an interior point from perimeter

Tags: regions, distance, nearest

By definition, the interior point is a point inside an arbitrary region like this:

[image]

In picture above, $y$ is an interior point of region. **My question** is how to find the distance of an interior point from it's boundary?

I have this Idea: By using the polygons, we can approximate the perimeter of region by a n-gon (n is large enough). Then by saving the coordinates of perimeter in two vectors, say $x$ and $y$, and use `Nearest` command we can find nearest point of perimeter from interior point ($y$).

I created data matrices ([find from here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j4s1y0ycjpxdn29/PI.mat)) in MATLAB and import to Mathematica.

```
imp = Import["PI.mat", "LabeledData"];
X = "KP" /. imp;
Y = "KI" /. imp;
```

But I can't know how to use `Nearest` command when we have large vectors like `X` and `Y` :

```
Nearest[{Flatten@X, Flatten@Y}, {3, 1.5}]
```

An error appears, because `Flatten@X`, `Flatten@Y` and `{3, 1.5}` are not the same length.

Comment: Not bad idea, not sure exactly what is in `X` `Y` but maybe you want: `Nearest[Transpose@{X, Y}, {1.5, 3}]`?

Comment: @Kuba X` and `Y` are two simple vectors. I used that, but not sure it's correct. But what does it (`Transpose`) do?

Comment: Did you look at `RegionDistance` and `SignedRegionDistance`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I interpreted your data correctly...

```
imp = Import["C:\\Users\\Rasher\\Downloads\\" <> "PI.mat", "LabeledData"];

(* get data into flat lists *)
X = "KP" /. imp // Flatten;
Y = "KI" /. imp // Flatten;

(* turn into X,Y point-sets *)
pts = Transpose[{X, Y}];

(* Find some point to boundary of poly *)
Nearest[pts, {3, 1.5}]

(*  {{2.67062, 2.7767}}   *)
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. Please correct `{1.5,3}` to `{3,1.5}`. (`{1.5,3}` is not interior point) Thanks for detailed answer.

Comment: I think it is not sufficient to compute the distance to the nearest point since the nearest line may be considerably closer.

Comment: @user2667048:done

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Can you give an example?

Comment: @user2667048 I mean something like this: `Graphics[{Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}], Red, PointSize[Large], 
  Point[{-0.4, 0.7}]}]`  -- I assume you want the distance to the edge, not one of the vertexes, correct?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes. you're right. But how I can't understand why "it's not sufficient to compute the distance to the nearest point"? In your example the nearest point obtain by drawing perpendicular line from red point to left side.

Comment: @user2667048 I'm a bit distracted at the moment and I may be reading rasher's answer wrong, but I think he is only returning the nearest vertex in the data.  I don't see a computation of distance at all, and especially not distance to the nearest point along the closest line. (I hope that makes sense.)  Anyway, IMHO neither existing answer is complete at this time.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: No, you're interpreting it right, I read the question as the OP wants the nearest *point* contained in the point-set. If in fact the OP means the nearest point of the connected polygon *described* by the point-set, my answer is not want they want (hence my caveat re: interpretation), and I'll delete it.

Comment: @rasher Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @user2667048: If I misinterpreted your intent, please comment, I can walk you through simple addition to do distance to polygon line...

Comment: @rasher Actually no, you interpreted well. But how can we find nearest point from polygon line in a simple way?

Comment: Do you know how to use `Norm`? If so, use the example to find the nearest point (a vertex of your polygon) then use `Norm` and the simple associated calculations to find the closest point on the two line segments from that vertex. If you're not familiar with the process, reply and I'll whip up the code and update my answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can compute the distance to all points within the shape in a single pass using [`DistanceTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DistanceTransform.html).  I was unable to load your data file in *Mathematica* 7 so I will use an arbitrary shape as an example:

```
bsf = BSplineFunction[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, .5}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, SplineClosed -> True];

pts = Table[bsf[x], {x, 0, 1, 0.01}];

gr =
 Graphics[{White, Polygon[pts]},
  Background -> Black,
  ImageMargins -> 0,
  PlotRangePadding -> 0,
  ImageSize -> 500
 ]

dist = ImageData @ DistanceTransform[gr];

dist // MatrixPlot
```

[image]

[image]

Obviously extracting the correct value(s) will take some scaling, but I don't have time at the moment to work it out.  Look at `Rescale` however.

Answer (score 3):

`RegionNearest` can also be an option

```
imp = Import["C:\\Users\\Ali Hashmi\\Downloads\\PI.mat","LabeledData"];
X = "KP" /. imp;
Y = "KI" /. imp;
threadeddata = Transpose[{Flatten@X, Flatten@Y}];
RegionNearest[Line@threadeddata, {3, 1.5}]

(* {2.67041, 2.77665} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the original data is not accessible anymore, a boundary is setup using `CirclePoints` with randomness added. After that `BSplineFunction` is used to create a smooth contour. Discretizing the graphic sets up the region.

```
SeedRandom[1234];
n = 6; (* Can experiment with more points *)
(pts = CirclePoints[{2, 0}, n]
   + RandomReal[1, {n, 2}]);(*//ListPlot[#,AspectRatio->Automatic]&*)

bsf = BSplineFunction[pts, SplineClosed -> True];
g1 = ListLinePlot[Table[bsf[x]
    , {x, 0, 1, 0.01}]
   , AspectRatio -> Automatic];
mreg = DiscretizeGraphics[g1];

Manipulate[
 Show@{
   Region[Style[mreg, Black], Frame -> True]
   , Graphics[{
     {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], 
      Point@{x + r Cos[θ], y + r Sin[θ]}
      , {Blue, AbsolutePointSize[6]
       , Point@
        RegionNearest[mreg, {x + r Cos[θ], y + r Sin[θ]}]
       , {Black, Dashed, Circle[{x, y}, r]}
       }
      }
     }
    , Frame -> True]
   }
 , {{x, 0.7}, -1 + r, 2.5 - r}
 , {{y, 0.5}, -1 + r, 2.5 - r}
 , {{r, 0.5}, 0.01, 1.2}
 , {{θ, 0}, 0, 2 π}
 , TrackedSymbols :> All
 ]
```

[image]