# Find Chebyshev center of a region by optimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Let's consider a region like this:

[image: Region]

The aim is to find the "[Chebyshev center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_center)" of the region. By using the polygons, one can approximate the perimeter of region by an $n$-gon ($n$ is large enough). Then by saving the coordinates of the perimeter in two vectors, say $x$ and $y$, and using Linear programming, compute the minimal-radius ball enclosing the region. But I want to try another way, an optimization!

I have two data sets, produced by MATLAB, ([get them from here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j4s1y0ycjpxdn29/PI.mat)) and I want to find the Chebyshev center by **optimization** (not linear programming). From [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41605/find-nearest-distance-of-an-interior-point-from-perimeter) I learnt how to find the **nearest distance** of an interior point from it's boundary:

```
X = "KP" /. imp // Flatten;
Y = "KI" /. imp // Flatten;
pts = Transpose[{X, Y}];
Nearest[pts, {3, 1.5}] 
(* {3,1.5} is a sample interior point *)
```

If I denote the nearest distance by $d$, the aim is to maximize $d$ (or minimize $-d$) over box inside region. (Like $x \in [1.5 \; 4.5] , y \in [0.5 \; 2]$.) The Chebyshev center will be obtained by maximizing $d$. But I can't define to Mathematica how treat with `FindMinimum` and `Nearest`.

Comment: [This recent thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40941/l-infty-norm-minimization) has a coded example of a bilevel optimization.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau That's really useful Q&A. But can we specify output argument for `Nearest` command like `NMaximize`? I'm not sure.

Comment: You would have to use `Nearest[...][[1]]` because `Nearest` returns a list. Also your inner function might need to be done as `nearest[x_?NumberQ,y_?NumberQ] := nf[{x,y}][[1]]` where `nf` is a `NearestFunction` created from your data points. Reason for this is to avoid any attempt by the outer optimization to use symbolic computations since the inner optimizer is in effect a black box.

Comment: Let me amend that. Could use `nearest[x_?NumberQ, y_?NumberQ] := 
 EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, nf[{x, y}][[1]]]`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Can I use this for nf function besides them?: `nf[x_, y_] := 
 Nearest[{pts, {x, y} }, 1.5 <= x <= 4.5, 0.5 <= y <= 2]`

Comment: No. Look up `Nearest`. It doesn't take arguments like 1.5<=x<=4.5. General remark: Go to basic documentation before you go to MSE.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Ok I found this: `nf = Nearest[pts]; nearest[x_?NumberQ, y_?NumberQ] := EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, nf[{x, y}][[1]]]; FindMinimum[{-nearest[x, y], 1.5 <= x <= 4.5, 0.5 <= y <= 2}, {x, y} ]`. I run the code and got result! Is this correct? If yes please answer to this question!

Comment: I don't know if it is correct. I don't know what result you got. I'm not even sure what point set you are using. The one I got from your link is not closed (has a horizontal leg and two that are not quite vertical, but nothing to close off the top).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau and I don't know what you mean by this sentence: 'has a horizontal leg and two that are not quite vertical, but nothing to close off the top'

Comment: It was an artifact of my not doing a good job plotting it. I now see the top. I'll post a regular response soon.

Comment: (1) "I want to find the chebyshev center by optimization (not linear programming)." I don't understand this statement. Linear programming is a form of optimization. (2) Never mind all that. There is a [linear time algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem#Linear-time_solutions) to find the smallest circle containing a set of points. Just apply it to the vertices of your polygon, and the center of the resulting circle is your desired result. No need for complicated numerical methods.

Comment: @RahulNarain Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Import and reconstruct the point set.

```
ptsdata = Import["/tmp/PI(1).mat", "LabeledData"];
pts = Transpose[({"KP", "KI"} /. ptsdata)[[All, 1, All]]];
```

Here is the region.

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{xcoords, ycoords}], PlotRange -> All, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Create the nearest function and the function we will maximize.

```
nf = Nearest[pts];
nearest[x_?NumberQ, y_?NumberQ] := 
 EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, nf[{x, y}][[1]]]
```

We add some constraints that pretty much force the point to stay on the inside. There are better ways to do this but that would take more work.

```
FindMaximum[{nearest[x, y], 1 <= x <= 6, 
  0 <= y <= 3, (y - 3) <= -1/3 (x - 3)^2}, {x, 3}, {y, 2}]

During evaluation of In[464]:= FindMaximum::eit: The algorithm does not converge to the tolerance of 4.806217383937354`*^-6 in 500 iterations. The best estimated solution, with feasibility residual, KKT residual, or complementary residual of {9.82931122747*10^-7,0.00262578662189,2.24578696996*10^-7}, is returned. >>

(* Out[464]= {1.42730059484, {x -> 3.36291430575, y -> 1.42730059479}} *)
```

`NMaximize` will give a slightly better result.

Comment: I tried the `NMaximize`, It gives better result. But when I compare the result to one obtained by Linear programming, I see a bit difference.

Comment: Does your linear programming look at the segments between polygon vertices? If so, that could alter slightly the distance-to-boundary values. The approach using `Nearest` will only give distance to vertices, not to segments.

Comment: Good interpretation.